# Dynamic carousel with django and bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a carousel to show some top rated products, the carousel works but I cant make work properly it seems that the problem is with the 'active' class . Each 'slide' shows 4 products.

This is my code

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for p in prod %}
<div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> // here is the problem
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h1>{{p.name}}</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

If I don't use the forloop.first, the carousel doesn't slide. And with this forloop.first, it shows only one item per slide, instead of 4 items.

The output in the inspector is :

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"> 
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3"> // Here I expect 4 columns and I get only 1
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with django. See the output html. Is there `active` class in output? Is there all the `div`s created in the loop?

Comment: The divs are created but it shows only one product each time, instead of 4 products.

Comment: Then it is most probably a problem with your carousel.

Comment: You have a single column in each row instead of having 4 col-sm-3 divs in one row.

Comment: @x3al Exactly, thats what I am having right now

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that you're trying to make a slide per each product: for each iteration of your loop you're creating a new `item` and put one `col-sm-3` into it.

You can change your view to pass a nested structure to template or try to do something like:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for p in prod %}
  {% cycle 'yes' '' '' '' as slidestart silent %}
    {% if slidestart %} <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> <div class="row">{% endif %}
       <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h1>{{p.name}}</h1>
       </div>
 {% if slidestart %} </div></div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

or use forloop.counter to put your items and rows each 4th row like that:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for p in prod %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}<div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> 
   <div class="row">{% endif %}
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <h1>{{p.name}}</h1>
     {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}</div>
   </div>
</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried both, but I get 4 rows with 1 product each. And the slider moves right/left only the first row.

Answer (score 2):

The cycle answer above was closing the item everytime. Needed an 'end' cycle. This worked for me.. Thx x3al!

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                {% for track in track_set.all %}
                {% cycle 'start' '' '' '' '' '' as slidestart silent %}
                    {% cycle '' '' '' '' '' 'end' as slideend silent %}
                {% if slidestart %} <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active      {%     endif %}"> <div class="row">{% endif %}
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   .. slide code ..
                </div>
                {% if slideend %} </div></div>{% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div {% if forloop.first %} class="item active" {% else %} class="item" {% endif %}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use this code to make 3 columned carousel, but the problem was when the object_list had number of items that are not dividable by the number of columns.

For example: it works with 6 columns because 6 % 3 = 0 but it doesn't work with 5 columns because 5 % 3 != 0

The problem was the cycle never got to the slidend and stopped prematurely, so I had to change the last if statement.

```
<div class="bs-news-wrapper">
    {% for a in articles %}
    {% cycle 'start' '' '' as slidestart silent %}
    {% cycle '' '' 'end' as slidend silent %}
    {% if slidestart %}<div class="item{% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> 
       <div class="row">{% endif %}
         <div class="col-md-4">
           #content
         </div>
    {% if not slidend and forloop.last or slidend %}
       </div>
    </div>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The change is in this line:

```
{% if not slidend and forloop.last or slidend %}
```

I hope this helps some future dwellers.